# How to open a collection item only on one client?

Tags: meteor

I have a meteor collection like this:

```
Cases = new Meteor.Collection('cases');
```

As well i have registered users (max 10). I now want to be able to "give" a single case to a registered user and be sure, that no other user is getting that specific case.

The User is working with the case (updating fields, deleting fields) and then sends it in some kind of archive after submitting the user should get a new case that is in the collection.

My thought was to have field called "locked" which initially is set to false and in the moment it is displayed at the user "locked" gets true and is not returned anymore:

```
return Cases.find({locked: false, done: false}, {limit: 1});
```

Any ideas how to do that in meteor?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to attach an `owner` field (or similar) to the case.  That would allow you to do things like:

- Only [publish](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish) the case to the user who is also the owner using something like:

```
Meteor.publish('cases/unassigned', function() {
    return Cases.find({owner: {$exists: false}});
});
Meteor.publish('cases/mine', function() {
    return Cases.find({owner: this.userId});
});
```

- Not [allow](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow) a user to update or delete a case if it's not assigned to them:

```
Cases.allow({
    update: function(userId, fieldNames, doc, modifier) {
        return userId === doc.owner;
    },
    delete: function(userId, doc) {
        return userId === doc.owner;
    }
});
```

Obviously, these would need amending for stuff like super-users and you probably need some [methods](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods) defined to allow users to take cases, but that's the general idea.

Comment: If two or more case-assignments are attempted at the same time, it's possible the `.allow` will permit both to be assigned to both users.  There is no guarantee that the `userId === doc.owner` code will protect you if they happen concurrently.

Comment: Firstly, if you make assignments using `$set`, this wouldn't be a real issue as the second assignee would simply take over the case from the first - they wouldn't both own it.  Secondly, if assignment is done via a method, this sort of concurrency problem should be easy to avoid as node runs in a single thread, so it should always know when a given case is at least in the process of being assigned.

Comment: Fair point about `$set`, you can query after to 'see who won'.  Node runs in a single thread per request.  If there are multiple requests and multiple node processes running (which is necessary if you have even a moderate amount of traffic) then those requests will be running concurrently - including methods.

Comment: Yes, with multiple processes, that's true, but the OP did say max 10 users. But in principal i agree with you, this cannot be relied upon.

Comment: First thanks for your comment.
Let's say I don't want to specify a userId to each case when they are created. Every user should be able to get a case as long as it is not locked by another user or archived.

Comment: The way I've presented it, any user that subscribes to `cases/unassigned` will get all the unassigned cases.  I'm suggesting you have a meteor method to actually assign a case at the appropriate time, in which you can just make sure the case in question is still unassigned and then add the userId (the method runs on the server).

Answer (score 0):

There are concurrency issues to deal with, to reliably allocate a case to only one person.

We need to solve two things:
1. Reliably assign the case to a user
2. Fetch the cases assigned to a user

Number 2. is easy, but depends on 1.

To solve 1., this should work:

```
var updated = Cases.update(
    {_id: <case-to-assign>, version: "ab92c91"},
    {assignedTo: Meteor.userId(), version: Meteor.Collection.ObjectID()._str});
if (updated) {
    // Successfully assigned
} else {
    // Failed to assign, probably because the record was changed first
}
```

Using this you can query for all of a users cases:

```
var cases = Cases.find({assignedTo: Meteor.userId()});
```

If 10 people try get a case at the same time, it should have a pre-set `version` field, and the MongoDB will only let the `.update` work once.  As soon as the `version` field changes (due to an `.update` succeeding) the remaining updates will fail as the `version` field could no longer match.

Now that the allocation has taken place reliably, fetching is very simple.

As suggested by @Kyll, the filtering of cases should be done inside a Meteor publication.

It would also make sense to perform the case-assignment inside a Meteor method.

**UPDATE:**

@richsilv's solution is simpler than this one, and works fine.

This solution is useful if you need to know who won immediately, without making further requests to the server.